# How can I save command outputs in PyMOL to a txt file?

Tags: python, scripting, pymol

I'm new to PyMOL, and I'm trying to write a python script that will generate a .txt file and save a PyMOL command output to it. Let's say it has an array containing names of pdb files and a for loop that aligns each one to some specific protein:

```
pdb = ["191L", "192L", "193L", "194L"]

cmd.fetch("190L")

for i in pdb:
cmd.fetch(i)
cmd.align(i, "190L")
```

PyMOL will calculate the RMSD for each alignment. How can I write my script so that it will take each RMSD and save it to a text file?

Here's what I have so far:

```
def get_rmsd():

cmd.fetch("190L")
for i in pdb:
   cmd.fetch(i)
   output = open("rmsd.txt", "w")
   data = cmd.align(i, "190L")
   data = str(data)
   output.write(data)
   stored.f.close()
```

When I call the function on PyMOL, it fetches and aligns the file like it's supposed to, but no text file is created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out the answer to my own question, the solution was embarrassingly easy lol.

Assign variables to each desired output, e.g.:

```
output = cmd.align("190L", "191L")
```

Run the script in PyMOL as is, then feed the python code into it line by line, beginning with "python" and closing with "python end." In my case, something like:

```
python
with open("rmsd.txt", "w") as f:
   f.write(output)
f.close()
python end
```

A really basic example but that's the gist of it.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use the `pymol.Scratch_Storage` class. I would keep it simple and do something like:

1. Create a new file "test.py"
2. Copy the following:

   ```
   from pymol import cmd
   import os


   def get_rmsd(pdbs, align_to):
       # a bit more reusable
       cmd.fetch(align_to)
       with open("rmsd.txt", "w") as w:
           # using context management will close the rmsd.txt automatically
           for pdb in pdbs:
               cmd.fetch(pdb)
               line = cmd.align(pdb, align_to)
               w.write(f"{line}\n")

       print(f"outfile: {os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'rmsd.txt')}")


   get_rmsd(["191L", "192L", "193L", "194L"], "190l")
   ```
3. Run script from PyMOL terminal with: `run test.py`

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in pdb:
   cmd.fetch(i)
   output = open("rmsd.txt", "w")
   data = cmd.align(i, "190L")
   data = str(data)
   output.write(data)
   stored.f.close()
```

try:

```
for i in pdb:
   cmd.fetch(i)
   output = open("rmsd.txt", "a")
   data = cmd.align(i, "190L")
   output.write("%s\n" % data)
   output.close()
```

should do the job