# Writing Pymol internal console commands and output in txt in PymolPy3

Tags: python, pymol

I have been trying to get (through the pymolpy3 package happy to change) the commands and output from the internal console saved in a txt file. So far, I can see the output generated in the console when I am running the script but no output is saved.

For reference

```
Uimport pymolPy3
import sys



# Redirect stdout to a log file
log_file_path = r'C:\path\logs.log'
sys.stdout = open(log_file_path, 'w')

# Launch PyMOL without the GUI
pm = pymolPy3.pymolPy3(0)

# Load structure
pdb = '4PXF'


# Fetch the PDB file for your protein
pm(f"fetch {pdb}, async=0")

# Select and show only existing residues (no missing residues)
pm("select existing_residues, resi first_existing_residue-last_existing_residue")
pm("show sticks, existing_residues")

# Get the amino acid sequence of existing residues

pm("iterate_state 1, existing_residues and name CA, resn")

#Save the session

# Quit PyMOL
pm("quit")

# Close the log file
sys.stdout.close()
```

It returns an empty log file, whereas the console output is

```
 PyMOL(TM) 2.5.5 - Incentive Product
 Copyright (C) Schrodinger, LLC
 
 This Executable Build integrates and extends Open-Source PyMOL.
 Detected 12 CPU cores.  Enabled multithreaded rendering.
PyMOL>fetch 4PXF, async=0
TITLE     Crystal structure of the active G-protein-coupled receptor opsin in complex with the finger-loop peptide derived from the full-length arrestin-1
 ExecutiveLoad-Detail: Detected mmCIF
 CmdLoad: ".\4pxf.cif" loaded as "4PXF".
PyMOL>select existing_residues, resi first_existing_residue-last_existing_residue
 Selector: selection "existing_residues" defined with 2844 atoms.
PyMOL>show sticks, existing_residues
PyMOL>iterate_state 1, existing_residues and name CA, resn
'ASN'
'VAL'
'GLY'
'TRP'
'SER'
'ARG'
...
 IterateState: iterated over 334 atom coordinate states.
```

As you can guess I am more interested in the 3 letter combinations.

Any help is welcome, as I have been stuck in this stage for a while now.
Thank you in advance!

PS. The previous stackoverflow post on something similar does not work in displaying isnide the txt the 3 letter amino acid residues

I have tried different system logs, running the automation scripts through cmd and straight into a txt file through bash commands. The previous stackoverflow answer does not work in my case

Comment: previous post is this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63362723/how-can-i-save-command-outputs-in-pymol-to-a-txt-file ?????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

without launching the GUI I can save the list of **aa**s with:

```
from pymol import (
                    
                    cmd ,
                    stored,
                    )


print('########## PYMOL VERSION ##########################################')
print('         ',  cmd.get_version() )
print('###################################################################')



cmd.log_open('log_file.txt')


# Load structure
pdb = '4PXF'



# Fetch the PDB file for your protein
cmd.fetch(pdb , 'async=0')

# print(a)

# Select and show only existing residues (no missing residues)
cmd.select('existing_residues', 'resi first_existing_residue-last_existing_residue')

           
cmd.show('sticks', 'existing_residues')

# Get the amino acid sequence of existing residues

stored.a ='\n'

cmd.iterate_state( 1, 'existing_residues and name CA' , 'cmd.log(resn), cmd.log(stored.a)')


# #Save the session
cmd.save('thisSession.pse')

cmd.log_close()
```

saves `log_file.txt` file:

```
....

ASN
ASP
ILE
ASP
VAL
MET
GLY
LEU
PLM
```

not able to save all the console output (and there is no console here !!) using [How can I save command outputs in PyMOL to a txt file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63650630/9877065) accepted answer

Same result using :

```
from pymol import (
                    
                    cmd ,
                    stored,
                    )


print('########## PYMOL VERSION ##########################################')
print('         ',  cmd.get_version() )
print('###################################################################')



import sys
sys.stderr = open('log.txt', 'w')
sys.stdout = open('log.txt', 'w')



# Load structure
pdb = '4PXF'

# Fetch the PDB file for your protein
cmd.fetch(pdb , 'async=0')



# Select and show only existing residues (no missing residues)
cmd.select('existing_residues', 'resi first_existing_residue-last_existing_residue')


           
cmd.show('sticks', 'existing_residues')

# Get the amino acid sequence of existing residues

cmd.iterate_state( 1, 'existing_residues and name CA' , "resn")

# #Save the session
cmd.save('thisSession.pse')
```

with output file `log.txt`:

```
PyMOL not running, entering library mode (experimental)
'ASN'
'GLY'
'THR'
'GLU'
'GLY'
....
....
....
MET'
'GLY'
'LEU'
'PLM'
```

Again not able to save all the console output (and there is no console here !!) using [How can I save command outputs in PyMOL to a txt file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63650630/9877065) accepted answer

Comment: Would it be possible to share the page of  the pymol package, as the only py package that I was able to find is PymolPy3

Comment: https://pymol.org/2/ --->  Visit the Open-Source Project : https://github.com/schrodinger/pymol-open-source

Comment: wikis or manuals https://pymolwiki.org/index.php/Main_Page , https://pymol.org/dokuwiki/doku.php?id=start , mailing list : https://sourceforge.net/projects/pymol/

Comment: not sure if pymol is into some of the linux repos

Comment: shouldnt you have pymol installed to run pymolPy3 ??

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PyMOL

Comment: pymolPy3 is just --> https://github.com/carbonscott/pymolPy3/blob/main/pymolPy3/pymolPy3.py

Comment: I have pymol (the application) installed, but, when calling from pymol import ... it raises an error

Comment: @Arpel sorry to hear that, you can ask a question aboit that. Not an expert on this , I am using prebuild anaconda

Comment: Ah, I see, could you share your environment so that I could trial it ?

Comment: https://omicx.cc/posts/2021-04-20-install-pymol-windows/   Step by Step Install Open Source Pymol 2.x in Windows by Conda

Comment: https://pymol.org/conda/ PyMOL installation with the "conda" Package Manager

Comment: See here too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74159499/how-can-i-use-pymol-api-from-python pymol comes with its own python interpreter, you need to get access to pymol path from.your python

Comment: https://www.biostars.org/p/42474/ same as above

Comment: Thank you so much, it seemed to be an issue with the downloaded version !